# Error when trying to call data from a JSON file in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to open Google Maps with data coming from a JSON file. I made the code and the map is working correctly. But there’s a mistake that I cannot solve.
Below is the code with the link to the example.
Where am I going wrong? I can not locate the error and fix it.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dados.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $(data).each(function(index, value) {});
                meuMapa(data);
        }
    }); 
        function meuMapa(data){
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'),{
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.6124627,-46.7972198),
                zoom: 15,
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions:{
                    style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                    position:google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
                    },
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            for (i=0; i<data.imoveis.length; i++){
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.imoveis[i].latitude, data.imoveis[i].longitude),
                        map: map,
                        icon: '' 
                    });
                }
        }
        meuMapa();
});
```

[Link to example that displays an error in the console.](http://oscaraguiar.com/estudo.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have two places in your code where you're calling `meuMapa`: once in the `success` handler:

```
success: function(data) {
  $(data).each(function(index, value) {});
  meuMapa(data);
}
```

and once at the bottom of your `$(document).ready(function() {`:

```
  meuMapa();
});
```

But `meuMapa` depends on its argument, `data`, being defined and having an `imoveis` property:

```
function meuMapa(data) {
  // ...
  for (i = 0; i < data.imoveis.length; i++) {
```

If the function is not provided an argument, the above will throw an error. Because the map is working already, just remove the superfluous `meuMapa();` call from the bottom.

It would also probably be beneficial not to implicitly create a global variable named `i`, as well: change your

```
for (i=0;
```

to

```
for (let i=0;
```

or use `forEach` instead.